# Atypical association of three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I'm writing an app about fishing.

- We have a `fish` model that contains some species.
- We have a `location` model that contains fishing spots.
- We have a `technique` model that contains some fishing techniques.

Each `location` may have multiple `fish`, so:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :fish
end
```

Each `fish` can be found in multiple locations, so:

```
class Fish < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations
end
```

The headache comes with the third model, because each `fish` can be caught with multiple `techniques` that depend on the `location`. In other words: there is something like a many-to-many relationship between `fish` and `technique` that changes for each `location`.

What kind of association should I use?

Comment: Are techniques and fish related or the relation is only between location and technique. Can you come up with an example to be more precise ?

Comment: Sure! I wanna fish SHARKS (fish), in BLUEDEEPS (location) I can fish them SPEARFISHING (technique) or CASTING (technique). In GREENROCK (location) I can fish them CASTING (technique) or with a NET (technique). But in GREENROCK (location) i can fish SEA BASS (fish) by SPEARFISHING (technique). Yes, it's an association triangle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_fishes
  has_many :fishes, :through => :location_fishes
end

class Fish  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_fishes
  has_many :locations, :through => :location_fishes
end

class LocationFish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fish
  belongs_to :location

  has_and_belongs_to_many :techniques
end
```

Please note that names of models and relations could be improved. Also you need to create proper migrations for these, especially you should not forget about creating habtm joining table.

With these definitions you can do something like this:

```
location = Location.find_by_name("Fancy lake")
some_fish = Fish.find_by_name("Trout")
techniques_for_location_and_fish = location.location_fishes.where(:fish_id => some_fish.id).first.techniques
```